# How to populate PostgreSQL database running inside a Docker container using Docker compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have a data dump file (without .sql extension) of an entire database created from an existing PostgreSQL database using **pg_dump** command. I want to populate a new PostgreSQL database - to run inside a Docker container - with that dump file while creating and running a Docker container for the first time. The docker container is created from [this](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) Docker image and ***docker compose*** will be used to run this new PostgreSQL database as service.

Comment: did you try the `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` (https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/)?

Comment: @LucasBazetto, 
Thanks it worked for me, but I had to change the pg_dump file (compressed/binary) to .sql format. That is, it did not work with pg_dump compressed / binary file.